# Azure Consumption Usage Details - throttling

Tags: azure, throttling, cost-management, consumption

x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-microsoft.consumption-tenant-requests : 12
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-microsoft.consumption-clientAppId-requests : 60

For Azure Consumption Usage Details there is an API throttling limit of 12 per tenant.
how to increase this throttle limit.

Comment: did you find out any solution for that? I'm running in the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Rate Limits are usually defined for a time window and reset at regular intervals. Most HTTP Clients should already handle the 429 response that you would get when the rate limit is hit.

For costlier operations, they are bound to have stricter limits but you can overcome this by leveraging caching of requests on your end so that multiple calls from different services don't eat up the rate limit.

For any limit increase requests, you have to open a support but I'm unsure if the limit can be increased as such.